# from git repository to website, as a preview. Can that be done?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

I have a git repository for a simple website project. Is there any way to have, let's say, stage.website.com that loads the file from the repository?

I don't mean magic, just, is there any tool or service to do that?

I see that with GitHub you can have a github.com third level domain and possibily use that. Is that correct? I am operating on Azure Devops, where I have the repository.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It could be useful, for my future questions on stackoverflow, knowing the reason of the downvotes. The platform was ok with posting my question.

Comment: +1 one for unfair voting. No I can't imagine where that is possible thats simple. A setup I can imagine is: you have a domain from a domaon provider and a small webspace. You `index.html` perform a **http GET** for content of the file in your repository an put it in a `iframe` or render it directly. For that your webspace need a  valid personal access token (`$PAT`). Presumably there are better solutions, but hope this help for the moment.

Comment: why dont you just publish the website? using some sort of ci\cd pipeline? or you want to pull the file from the repo using github rest api? why? just upload the file to a blob and grab it from there. or package the file inside the web app. as for the downvote (it was not mine): I personally think - this question is either unclear or not suitable for SO. I dont see how this is a coding related question.

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for your comment. I would like to say that I have understood everything you've written, but... I have create a pipeline build. I also have created a pipeline release, but "uplad to a blobo or package..." would you please help me understand that?

Comment: well, you can create a separate pipeline to upload the file you talk about to some sort of storage medium where you can access it from the web app, without having to go through the github api

Comment: @MarTin thanks for your kind support. I just thought I could "deploy to server space" AND the content of the git repo would push the files there, so I and the other team members could evaluate the job.

Comment: @4c74356b41...ehm...how? :) are you familiar with azure devops interface? Once I have create e new pipeline, how do i give it a ftp server as storage medium?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have found these instructions:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops It looks like everything is going ok, but when an agent is going to be created, it just gets stuck. The ftp folder in the remote server is still empty.

Comment: Please check the log  after setting `System.Debug=true` in pipeline. You may get useful info there about why the deploy not worked as expected.